# Problem With Defined For Loop in Haskell

Tags: haskell, for-loop, interpreter

I have come across the same problem, but maybe I can give a little more context in what is going on for my situation and maybe that can help.

Creating an interpreter with typedef:

```
interp :: Env -> Expr -> M Val
```

that handles for loops in this format:

```
for ( var = expr to expr ) ( expr )
```

Data constructor defined as the following:

```
data Val =
   ValInt Int
 | ValBool Bool
 | ValFun (Val -> M Val)
 | ValRecFun (Val -> Val -> M Val)
 | ValRef Loc
 | ValNil
```

And an extended environment defined as:

```
extendEnv :: Identifier -> Val -> Env -> Env
extendEnv var val (Env bs) = Env ((var,val):bs)
```

Here's where I am:

```
interp env (For x e1 e2 e3)       = do
                                      (ValInt v1) <- interp env e1
                                      (ValInt v2) <- interp env e2
                                      if (v1 < v2)
                                        then 
                                            let nenv = extendEnv x e1 env in do
                                                interp nenv e3
                                                interp env (For x e1 e2 e3)
                                        else return ValNil
```

Obviously, I don't want to pass "e1" into the recursive call of the for loop, but rather the evaluated "v1" variable incremented.... but I can't figure out how to pass it the correct expression of "v1". Is this enough direction to get a little help?:)

### ****UPDATE****

Ok, here's my attempt at creating the doLoop that will do my looping work.  I feel as if it is a little over-engineered, but I could not figure out how to call the "env" in doLoop without passing it in the call.

```
interp env (For x e1 e2 e3)= do
                          (ValInt v1) <- interp env e1
                          (ValInt v2) <- interp env e2
                     return doLoop x v1 v2 env e3

doLoop :: Identifier -> Int -> Int -> Env-> Expr -> M Val
doLoop x v1 v2 env e3 = 
                 if v1 > v2 then return ValNil
                 else
                    let nenv = extendEnv x (ValInt v1) env in
                    interp nenv e3
                    doLoop x (ValInt (v1+1)) v2 nenv e3
```

**UPDATE**

It seems to be having a problem with my For definition, namely:

```
return doLoop x v1 v2 env e3
```

It can't match the expected type `M Val' against my inferred type`Expr -> M Val'.

Am I making some silly error here?

Comment: you also don't want to pass e1 into the extendEnv call, I believe?

Comment: Anyway, the fundamental issue is that you shouldn't be calling (interpreting if you prefer) For itself recursively, but should create a recursive loop in your host language (Haskell) which interprets the meaning of the for loop.

Comment: Also good job on asking a clear question, but you really should make clear that this is homework of some sort.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  I am going to make an attempt at an inner doLoop that can "do" the actual looping and will get it up here asap.

Comment: @sclv: That depends on if you want to limit the amount of 'meta' in your interpreter. For the real world you don't care too much (as long as the semantics are the same), but for an assignment you probably want to make it as non-meta as possible. As an aside, some of this code looks awfully familiar...

Comment: return (doLoop x v1 v2 env e3) -- return is just a regular function. you need to get the scoping right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Obviously, I don't want to pass "e1"
>   into the recursive call of the for
>   loop, but rather the evaluated "v1"
>   variable incremented.... but I can't
>   figure out how to pass it the correct
>   expression of "v1". Is this enough
>   direction to get a little help?:)

You've already got the 'pure' representation of the variable `e1` in `v1`, you can simply add 1 to `v1` and repack it. Replace `makeConstExpr` with whatever it is you use to construct an `Expr`.

```
interp env (For var start end body) = do 
 (ValInt s) <- interp env start
 (ValInt e) <- interp env end 
 if s <= e 
   then
       let envn = extendEnv var (ValInt s) env in do
     interp envn body
     interp env (For var (makeConstExpr (s + 1)) end body) 
   else return ValNil
```

(I seem to recall typing this recently...)

Some would argue that it's better to abstract this using built in functions and making a meta-interpreter. As this is an assignment, you're probably better off making it as non-meta as possible to increase your understanding of the forces at work.

**Edit:** Depending on how you're doing your mutation, you may want to pass `nevn` instead of `env` in `interp env (For var (ValInt (s + 1)) end body)`.

Comment: I don't want to pass start into the extendedEnv as an expression though, do I?  Since extendEnv :: Identifier -> Val -> Env -> Env, it can't take start (as it is an Expr at this point)

Comment: @user546459: I missed that, good catch. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost there. Take a look at this (working with Ints directly, packing them into Vals when appropriate, fixed a little scoping issue with parens, and only passing env in the recursive call):

```
doLoop :: Identifier -> Int -> Int -> Env -> Expr -> M Val
doLoop x v1 v2 env e3 = 
                 if v1 > v2 then return ValNil
                 else
                    let nenv = extendEnv x (ValInt v1) env in 
                    interp nenv e3
                    doLoop x (ValInt (v1+1)) v2 env e3
```

Comment: It seems to be having a problem with my For definition, namely:
     return doLoop x v1 v2 env e3

It can't match the expected type `M Val' against my inferred type `Expr -> M Val'.  Am I making some silly error here?

Comment: Change the last line to `doLoop x (v1+1) v2 env e3`.

Comment: It's actually the call in my interpreter that's complaining, not the doLoop function itself. Am I passing something incorrectly?

Comment: You need "return (doLoop x v1 v2 env e3)", I think